# SQLAlchemy: How to get result in a list while querying single columns of table using all()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following Python code:

```
units_abilities = (Session.query(UnitsAbility.id)
                          .filter(UnitsAbility.unit_id == unit.id)
                          .all())
print units_abilities
```

When I run it, i get `[(1L,), (2L,)]`, but I need list, not list of tuples

How can I get `units_abilities` like `[1L, 2L,]`?

I am using *SQLAlchemy 0.7.3* and *Python 2.7*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
>>> units_ability = [(1L,), (2L,)] # units_abilities = (Session....all())
>>> [x for (x,) in units_ability]
[1L, 2L]
```